# TYPO3 RealURL does not work after Backup

Tags: http-status-code-404, backup, typo3, realurl

My RealURL path segments do not work anymore since a Backup.

I had TYPO3 7.6.10 on my Windows PC.
Then i installed TYPO3 7.6.11 on my new Mac.

I made a dump file of the database and copied all files of my TYPO3 Project.

After finishing, I could successfully login into the backend.

The only problem I have is, that my RealURL does not rewrite my paths anymore.

Actually my first page is called `localhost/project/home/` instead of `localhost/project/index.php?id=2`.
However, the first one always ends up in a 404 - Error.

I don't know why that happens, since i also copied the _.htacces file in the project folder too. Or is that not the right way to back up?

Hope someone can help me.

**EDIT**
Problem solved: Since OSX is hiding some sepcial files like the .htaccess, i had to make them visible so i could copy them. Now everything is working as it shall!

Comment: The file has to be named `.htaccess`, in the default Apache setup.

Comment: There is no .htaccess in my XAMPP. Only a _.htaccess in my project folders. Do i have to create a .htaccess somehere in my XAMPP folder? I tried to rename the _.htaccess into .htaccess, but i couldn't since it was not allowed because of the "." as a first character.

Comment: It has to be named `.htaccess`, the `_.htaccess` file is just an example file. The underscore is there to prevent it from being interpreted. It's somehow possible to rename it to `.htaccess`, even on Windows, [which is possible](http://superuser.com/questions/64471/create-rename-a-file-folder-that-begins-with-a-dot-in-windows).

Comment: @Joggal Please add your solution as self-answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Problem solved:**

Since OSX is hiding some sepcial files like the .htaccess, i had to make them visible so i could copy them.

Now everything is working as it shall!